# JS / VueJS динамические табы с объектами

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, tabs

Доброго времени суток.

Мне необходимо реализовать табы на чистом JS, либо на VueJS (желательно всё же на чистом) которые находятся на фронтенде изначально без единого "таба".

В чем заключается проблема и что вообще мне нужно? Постараюсь описать.

Бекенд генерирует JSON объект таба подобного типа (можно и другого вида):

```
{
    "tabs1": [
        {
            "name": "Tab 1",
            "message": "Первый tab"
        }
    ],
    "tabs2": [
        {
            "name": "Tab 2",
            "message": "Второй tab"
        }
    ],
}
```

На фронтенде есть определенный div, в случаи, если массив Tabs не пустой, то необходимо создать таб с именем name и содержимым message.

Как можно реализовать подобное?
Есть мысль, чтобы создать функцию "addTabs", которая будет принимать в себя имя и содержимое, а уже после циклом добавлять табы.

Comment: не совсем понятно что мешает создать компонент который будет принимать массив *табов* и генерировать соответствующую разметку

Comment: @bald Массив табов должен быть в самом файле Vue, либо получать массив к примеру через axios из "вне", но сам массив объектов должен находиться в html файле, который генерируется PHP сервером.

Comment: если исходные данные для генерации табов находятся в html генерируемых сервером то отредактируйте свой вопрос добавлением этой информации в вопрос(пример ответа сервера тоже желателе), так же добавьте соответствующую метку `php`